# What does "the map $i$ is transverse to the vector field $X$ everywhere" mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields, tangent-bundle, foliations

**Geometric Theory of Foliations**, Page **28**. The Lines **7** and **8** from below.

What does "the map $i$ is transverse to the vector field $X$ everywhere" mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that $i(B^{m-1})$ is nowhere tangent to $X$. You can infer this from the next two sentences as well since $\Phi^{-1}|_{V}$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: How could this be? $X$ is a non-singular vector field. Could you, please, explain it a little bit more since I am confused? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Non-singular means $X$ does not vanish on $M$. A simple example is the constant vector field  $X = (1,0)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Setting $p=(0,0)$ you could take $i:B^1=(-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ to be $i(t) = (0,t)$. Then $i((-1,1))$ is transverse to $X$.

Comment: The vector field you have defined attaches to every point ($x,y$) the vector $1×x+0×y$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: This vector field vanishes at the origin. It is supposed to be non-singular.

Comment: A singular point of $X$ is a point $p$ for which $X(p)=0$. It says that $X$ is a vector field on $M$ without singular points, so $X$ does not vanish anywhere on $M$. You can see that two sentences later itsays "since $X(p)\neq 0$."

Comment: I was talking about the vector field you have defined X=(1,0), it is singular or what?

Comment: The vector field I defined is not singular since it has the constant value of $(1,0)$ everywhere which is not zero. It looks like this: tinyurl.com/4c3txwmu